# MongoDB: Getting the Nth element from array, when N should be derived from the doc itself

Tags: arrays, mongodb, performance, optimization, nosql

Say I have a doc of the format:
{
   arr: [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, ...., {id: m-1}, {id: m}],
   n: number
}

so an array of objects and an n property. I want to get the nth element of the array (arr[n]).
each object in the array also has an id property that correlates to it's index so another option is to query the array for the element with id=n.

I did some research on how to get the Nth item of an array using $slice, as well as on $elemMatch.
I couldn't figure out how can I write a query that returns the Nth element of the array, when I don't know the N value, and must get it from the doc itself during the same query.

I could get the entire array, but it can get very large (even 100K+ elements) and so I'd much rather get the one I need, either in the query or the projection part of the find.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sefi

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :)

Turns out the way to do it is by using aggregate and not find, and defining query vars using $let:

```
db.getCollection('<collection>').aggregate([
{$match: {key: '<key>'}},
{$project: {
    obj: {
        $let: {
            vars: {
                idx: '$n',
                objects: '$arr'
            },
            in: {$arrayElemAt: ['$$objects', '$$idx']}
        }
    }
}}
])
```